# How to deal with null HttpContext.Current when using auth filters with async/await?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In one of apis in my controller I need to reference HttpContext.Current.  Everything worked fine until I implemented a custom authentication filter.  The filter uses async methods with await.  However, with the filter in place, the HttpContext.Current is null when it reaches my controller.
I'm assuming that this is because my controller executes on a different thread that it used to due to async/await in the filter.
If this is the case, how should I access the 'original' context in my controller?
This is a bit disappointing because filters seem like a good pluggable idea but unfortunately they come with some [serious] disadvantages.
Sample pseudo code:

```
public class TestAuthFilter : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    private static string validationClaim = "testClaim";
    private tokenValidationUri;

    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }

    public TestAuthFilter(string tokenValidationUri)
    {
        this.tokenValidationUri = tokenValidationUri;
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // We are not adding any authentication challenges to the response
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

        if (authorization == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (authorization.Scheme != "Bearer")
        {
            return;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Missing access token", request);
            return;
        }

        string token = authorization.Parameter;
        IPrincipal principal = await AuthenticateAsync(token, cancellationToken);
        if (principal == null)
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid access token", request);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Principal = principal;
        }
    }

    public async Task<IPrincipal> AuthenticateAsync(string token, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {                    
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(tokenValidationUri + token, cancellationToken);

                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var success = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenValidationSuccess>();
                            if (success.audience.Equals(validationAudience, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                            {
                                TestPrincipal principal = new TestPrincipal([...]);
                                return principal;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var error = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenValidationError>();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Pass the context as a parameter.

Comment: How can I pass the context as a parameter to my controller?  This implies that I should be able to grab the 'original' context at some point and then pass it to the controller.  However, the methods of my controller are invoked by the framework.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Could you submit your custom filter?

Comment: I just posted sample code.

Comment: Your `AuthenticationFilter` must have `OnAuthentication()` method. Could you submit it too. And also where are you calling `HttpContext.Current` I could not find it in your code.

Comment: IAuthenticationFilter has only 2 methods as per docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.iauthenticationfilter(v=vs.118).aspx.  OnAuthentication() is not one of them.   I call HttpContext.Current in methods of my controller (not included).  As I mentioned before, if I remove the filter then the context in the controller is not null.

Comment: @bdristan: Are you targeting .NET 4.5, ***and*** have you set `httpRuntime@targetFramework` to `4.5` in your `web.config`?

Comment: OMG! That's it.  I now recall reading about targetFramework=4.5 somewhere but ignored it thinking that setting target framework to 4.5 in project settings was equivalent to the former.  I would flag your comment as an answer but I can't.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to include "targetFramework=4.5" in  in web.config.  Credits go to Stephen Cleary - see comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good link on `AuthenticateAsync` in `WebAPI`: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Should take as parameter `HttpAuthenticationContext`, which contains thread safe versions of `ActionContext` and `HttpRequestMessage` Request.

Here's the inheritance chain to get there:

```
(HttpRequestMessage)System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpAuthenticationContext.ActionContext.ControllerContext.Request
```